# What is the interpretation of the reduction modulo $p$ of the modular curve $X(N)$ for $p$ dividing $N$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $N>3$ be an integer.
The modular curve $X(N)$ is the compactification of the scheme parametrising triples $(E,t,t)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over a field of characteristic 0, and $t,t'$ are generators of the $N$-torsion sub-group. That curve is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$: let us denote by $X(N)_{mod\,p}$ its reduction modulo $p$ for a prime $p$ dividing $N$.

Question: Is there a known interpretation of that curve $X(N)_{mod\,p}$ as a moduli space of some geometric objects ?

Comment: Yes --- replace the usual level structure with a "Drinfeld level structure". See Katz, Nicholas M.; Mazur, Barry, Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves.
Ann. of Math. Stud., 108 Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1985

Comment: Thank you very much @anon. This is a big book: would it be possible to have a rough intuition into simple words of what is going on ?... Or not ?